# For any two sets how to prove: (1) $A ⊆ B$ (2) $A ∪ B = B$ (3) $A − B = B − A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove these statements are equivalent and I'm stuck at proving the second one. I started by proving that  $A \cup B \subseteq B$.

$x \in (A \cup B)  $ then $ x \in B$

$x \in A$ or $x \in B$ then $ x \in B$

$ x \in A $ then $x \in B$ is true from the first assumption

$x \in B$ then $x \in B$ is true because B is a subset of itself

This was in the first direction. ($A \cup B \subseteq B$) But when I try to do it in the other direction I get this.

$B \subseteq A \cup B$

$x \in B$ then $x \in (A \cup B)$

$x \in B$ then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$

I can prove that $x \in B$ then $x \in B$ again but how do I prove $x \in B$ then $x \in A$? ($B \subseteq A$)

Comment: Are you trying to prove that those statement are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, I am. But I think I need to keep in my all 3 statements at the same time.

Comment: $A-B=B-A$ only if $A=B$ (in which case $A-B=B-A=\emptyset$), which is definitely *not* equivalent with (weaker) $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. Could I please get a deeper explanation?

Comment: @GeTo I suggest that you rewrite your question because it is not clear what you are trying to prove. Those statements are not equivalent

Comment: I think this is better? I'm trying to determine if these statements are equivalent. Now I know they are not but how can I prove that? Do I make another question just concerning this?

Comment: @GeTo so you want to determine whether not these statements are equivalent and why?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm not a native speaker and this is already confusing.

Comment: The context of your question is missing. **Why** are you trying to prove those three statements are equivalent (and the third is **not** equivalent to the other two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be any sets.

$(1) \implies (2).\quad$ Suppose that $A \subseteq B.$ Let $x \in A \cup B.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
x \in A \cup B & \implies x \in A \vee x \in B\\
& \implies x \in B \vee x \in B & \text{($A \subseteq B$)}\\
& \implies x \in B.
\end{align}$$

Hence, $A \cup B \subseteq B.$ Now, let $y \in B.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
y \in B & \implies y \in A \vee y \in B\\
& \implies y \in A \cup B.
\end{align}$$

Hence $B \subseteq A \cup B.$ Therefore $A \cup B = B.$

$(2) \implies (3)? \quad$ No. Let $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}.$ Note that $A \cup B = \{1,2\} = B$ But $A - B = \emptyset \neq \{2\} = B -A.$

$(3) \implies (1). \quad$ Suppose that $A - B = B - A.$ Then $A = B.$ Therefore $A \subseteq B.$

$(2) \implies (1). \quad $ Suppose that $A \cup B = B.$ Let $x \in A.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
x \in A & \implies x \in A \vee x \in B\\
& \implies x \in A \cup B\\
& \implies x \in B & \text{($A \cup B = B$)}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore $A \subseteq B.$

$(3) \implies (2). \quad$ Suppose that $A \cup B = B.$ Hence $A = B.$ Then

$$A \cup B = B \cup B = B.$$

$(1) \implies (3)? \quad$ No. Use the same example used in proving that $(2) \implies (3)$ is false.

So the implications $(1) \implies (2), (3) \implies (1), (2) \implies (1)$ and $(3) \implies (2)$ are true, while $(2) \implies (3)$ and $(1) \implies (3)$ are false.

More, you can see that $(1) \iff (2)$ so $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the only equivalent statements. $\quad \square$

Comment: So if I get a similar problem, I prove all the possible implications one by one?

Comment: No, to prove that $(1) \iff (2) \iff (3)$ you only need to prove that $(1) \implies (2), (2) \implies (3), (3) \implies (1)$ the other implications come “automatically” (because of the transitividade of $\implies$).

Comment: In this case I had to prove one by one in order to show the true implications and the false ones